# How to upload m4a audio files to Google Speech to Text API with fluent-ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I'm trying to grapple with uploading m4a audio files to Google Speech to Text API. A lot of existing questions suggest that using `fluent-ffmpeg` can solve this, but it is quite challenging for me.

### Details

All below codes are written by `TypeScript`.

With `express` and `multer`, I upload `.m4a` file to `Node.js` server. The uploaded file should be converted into `.wav` and upload to the Google Cloud Storage bucket at once. (Using only memory)

I'm using [`fluent-ffmpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) to convert the audio files.

### What I tried

```js
const file = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
const fileStream = file.createWriteStream({
  resumable: false,
});

const readableStream = new Readable();
readableStream.push(req.file.buffer);
readableStream.push(null);

const command = ffmpeg(readableStream).outputFormat('wav');
command.on('error', (err) => {
  res.status(500).send('Error converting audio file');
});
command
  .pipe(fileStream)
  .on('error', (err) => {
    res.status(500).send('Error uploading file to GCS');
  })
  .on('finish', () => {
    res.locals.publicUrl = format(`gs://${bucket.name}/${file.name}`);
    next();
  })
  .end(req.file.buffer);
command.run();
```

### Postman Result

```
500 Internal Server Error: Error converting audio file
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you manually convert your `m4a` audio file first into `wav` and not hard coded. You can also use `ffmpeg` for conversion. Use this if you haven't installed ffmpeg on your terminal or cloud shell.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Then enter this code.

```
ffmpeg -i audiofile.m4a newaudiofile.wav
```

Upload your file to **Google Cloud Storage bucket**. If your file is more than a minute, use [Asynchronous speech recognition](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#transcribe_long_audio_files_using_a_google_cloud_storage_file), if not, try [synchronous speech recognition](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize) for short audio file transcription.

Comment: Converting M4A to WAV is a workaround - but not a solution to the actual issue.